# How to remove Query Strings such as date= or author= from url in Wordpress using htaccess

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I used following htacces code for removing date= query string from the URL

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)date=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^paivamaara/(.*)$ /paivamaara/$1?date=%1 [L,R]
```

its working on simple PHP file but when applied to Wordpress; its not working anymore.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

That rule doesn't look right for removal of `date` parameter because you are adding it back in target.

You can use this redirect rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line to remove a specific query parameter:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?date=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,NE,L]

# all WP rules come below this line
```

Note that this rule allows your query parameter to be positioned anywhere in a query string.

Here is [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rNgWud/1) for the regex used above.

Comment: @Suhail: Did this work out?